# SetText inside OnCreateViewHolder sets text on more than one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

[image]

When i click the increment sign on the item, it should increment the number for only that item i clicked at. However, i scroll down and i find some other items are incremented as well.

Here is my code

```
    public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Dish> dishList;
private CartFragment fra;






public CartAdapter(Context mContext, List<Dish> dishList, CartFragment fragment) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dishList = dishList;
    this.fra=fragment;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_cart, parent, false);

    final MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    holder.inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int i=Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString())+1;
            holder.number.setText(i+"");
            //fra.addPrice(p);

        }
    });

    holder.dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString())>1){
                int i=Integer.parseInt(holder.number.getText().toString())-1;
                holder.number.setText(i+"");
                //fra.addPrice(-p);}

            }
        }});
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Dish dish = dishList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(dish.getName());
    holder.ing.setText(dish.getIngredients());
    holder.price.setText(dish.getPrice());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dishList.size();
}
```

What is the problem?

I tried calling the onClickListener on the bind view but the same bug keeps occurring.

Comment: return new MyViewHolder(itemView) from onCreateViewHolder after inflating the layout and set the click listener in the MyViewHolder class

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I tried it as well but the problem is still there. It duplicates every 6 items

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I need to override these two methods in my adapter

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```